Psycho guy is controlled by a "mother figure" from a theater screen and turns into a serial killer
There is this really disturbing movie I've been trying to find recently, where a guy apparently in a demential state, watches a movie on theater where there is a "mother", who always calls a man's name and brainwashes him into obeying her or something. Her voice was from an old woman, pretty creepy and annoying, much like the voice of the medium of Poltergeist. The guy seems to be getting controlled by this "mother" from the movie.
Later, there are two girls that go watch the same movie on the theater with that guy, and suddenly the guy starts killing everyone inside with a gun. The girls manage to escape but one remains inside the theater, hidden. The other goes to get help from police.
The scene that mostly comes to mind is the girl hidden in the toilet watching the killer walking from under the door, while he was searching for her.
In the end both girls survive I think, and the police manages to catch the killer in the theater.
The movie is from around the 80s I believe. I watched it in television. Can't remember anything else. 

I think the film you are describing is Anguish from 1987. It involves a disturbed man compelled to kill, just as described in the question. From IMDB:As John is cutting out the dead Caroline and her husband's eyes, the image slowly pulls back to reveal that this whole thing is a movie being shown to a small audience in a small movie theatre. The slasher film is called The Mommy and it is having a matinee showing in this theater somewhere in Los Angeles. Among the audience are two teenage girls named Patty (Talia Paul) and Linda (Clara Pastor). Patty is disgusted and frightened by the film and of John's character. The unfeeling Linda, munching on popcorn, tells Patty that it is only a movie.
In the film, John is called home by his mother and she confronts him to kill all of the people in the city saying "all of the eyes of the city will be ours"...
Mother tells John to go for more people in the theater. John sits behind a couple as the woman (Diane Pinkley) goes for more popcorn, and he kills the unaccompanied husband (Benito Porcino).
In a women's room stall, Patty sees a pair of shoes outside the door and when they are gone, she runs back into the theater and tells her that the weird looking man was in the bathroom. Linda points him out, still sitting in his chair. But Patty is convinced that a man was in the bathroom and she persuades Linda to go check. Linda, who wants more popcorn anyway, finally agrees to check it out and tells Patty to stay to tell her what happened.
By the way: the creepy and annoying voice (like the medium from Poltergeist) is because the actress is the same: Zelda Rubinstein.

Haven't watched yet to be absolute certain, but that's exactly it. Haha, funny how I recalled this movie because I rewatched a trailer of Poltergeist a few days ago. I should have noticed it was the same woman. Thank you very much.
